# How can I get my program to run the future values correctly?

Tags: java

Okay here is my code that I'm trying to create from a practice code from a text book. The question asked me to create a java console program that prompts the user to enter an investment amount and the interest rate. Furthermore, the program should use these inputs to calculate and list the future values (I'm doing it up to 5 periods).So for example, if I use an input such as 500 for Amount and 1 for interest rate the numbers that the program should display (from periods 1-5) are: 505.00, 510.05, 515.15, 520.30, 525.51. Any tips or help would be appreciated thank you! ^-^

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FutureValues {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString;
    char letter = 'c';

    // Prompt the user to enter investment amount
    while(letter == 'c') {
      System.out.print("Enter your investment amount: ");
      int InvestmentAmount = input.nextInt();

    // Prompt the user to enter interest rate
      System.out.print("Enter the interest rate (%): ");
      int InterestRate = input.nextInt();  
      System.out.println("    "); 

    // Display the header
      System.out.println("The future values are: ");
      System.out.println("    ");

    // Display "Period" title and "rate" title
      System.out.println("Period        " + InterestRate + "% ");
      System.out.println("\n------     ------");

    // Display table body 

      for (int h = 1; h <= 5; h++) {
         System.out.print(h);
         System.out.printf("          %4.2f",  (double) (InterestRate) + 1 * InvestmentAmount);
         System.out.println("      ");

      }

      System.out.println("     ");
      System.out.print("Enter c to continue or any other character to quit: ");
      String character = input.nextLine();
      inputString = input.nextLine();
      letter = inputString.charAt(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what seems to be the trouble?

Comment: I'm trying to make the code calculate the interest for the amount for up to 5 periods and all I can get it to do is run the same value for each 5 periods (and not a one of them is right) lol I'm new to programming but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Do you know what compound interest is?

Comment: yes but I'm not sure how to "code" compound interest.

Comment: after each period , do you not think that your investment amount would change?

Comment: no just the rate should increase by 1 (what ever the interest rate the user types in). So if they say 1 % it will need to for the next period go to 2%.

Comment: so what is your input and what is your output?

Comment: my input I'm using is 500 = Investment Amount & 1 = interest rate. My output is a table that displays 5 periods of this amount with (suppose to be) an increasing interest rate. My output is 501.00 every time.

Comment: Well, you almost got it. Check your for-loop and the operators, note in what order they come.  Try the *= operator, but keep track of if interest is a percentage or a fraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing your `InvestmentAmount` and `InterestRate` as double instead of int (will save you from casting and creating an extra variable)

Then, your for loop needs to not only "print" your InvestmentAmount, but also update it, based on your interest.

```
  for (int h = 1; h <= 5; h++) {
    InvestmentAmount *= 1 + InterestRate / 100;
    System.out.print(h);
    System.out.printf("          %4.2f",  InvestmentAmount);
    System.out.println("      ");
  }
```

The Interest Rate is divide per 100 to give you a percentage (otherwise, 1 = 100%, 2 = 200%, etc...)

Comment: I got it! Thank you this is what I needed it to do thanks a lot!!